# Find equally distributed nodes in a graph / central nodes of communities

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking for some help regarding network theory. Maybe there are just some buzzwords / keywords I don't know and I hope you can help me to find the correct term for my future research.

So, I am looking for a metric to find equal distributed nodes inside a graph. To be more precise, I want to find central/well connected nodes that are equalyl distributed. I know different centrality measures, but theses measures aim for centrality, hence they will be over represented in the center of a graph.

My idea was to first use natural cuts or something similar to split a graph into smaller subgraphs/communities/cuts and then make use of any centrality measures.

Is there a more elegant solution?

**For a better understanding:** 
Given is a multidigraph, representing a road network (fixed nodes). The task is to find 'central'/ well connected nodes like transportation hubs, with the condition, that they cover every region of the graph equally. With equal distributed I mean the distance on the graph (edgeweight).

I don't have any starting node. I don't know if it's feasible to calculate [reachability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability) or something similiar for every node in the graph.

**Update:** To make it more clear I try to use an example. Given is a road network of a city. The city has different districts. I try to find the most central nodes for each district. You can exchange the word 'district' with 'region','natural cut' or 'subgraph'. In the end I need a subset of nodes, that represents the differents districts equally (one central node for each district).

Thanks alot in advance for help/feedback!

Comment: No idea what is meant by a region of the graph, or what it means for a node to cover a region, or what it would mean to cover all regions equally. What specifically  are you doing as an attempt, and what specifically is wrong with the results that you are obtaining?

Answer (score 1):

Some formal buzzwords are "facility location" and even more specifically "[metric k-center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_k-center)/[vertex k-center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_k-center_problem)", where you minimize the maximum distance/sum of distances to selected hubs. But I suppose you'll find more practical stuff starting from [cluster analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis), specifically [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) and variants, or [community detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822265/are-there-implementations-of-algorithms-for-community-detection-in-graphs).